# Splitting string into separate strings with word lengths

Tags: python, string, split

I have a sentence

```
s = 'john had a little blue car'
```

which I want to split into three different strings (of word length 2) to obtain

```
'john had'
'a little'
'blue car'
```

How can I do this using split? First I tried splitting via

```
s.split(" ")
```

to give

```
['john', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'blue', 'car']
```

how can I now take that list of words and join them to obtain the result I want?

Answer (score 2):

### Regex

Using a regex:

```py
import re

r = r"(\w+\s+\w+)"
s = "john had a little blue car"
m = re.findall(r, s)
```

- `(\w+\s+\w+)`
   <sub>[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k8jirA/1)</sub>

  - `\w`: matches any word character
  - `\s`: matches any whitespace
  - `+` : as many times possible
- [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

  > Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings or tuples.

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Fcs7DsMgEEXRflbxRAUicuPaO6HBMRFYw0fjiaKsnjjNLY50x1dzb@ucpY4uCklEgg1ibPj4cPm7zpDeZM6eG3I8EMFFlRN2fic8oxiq/yctr9KOyGzlAXVEQ0pTW92cPw)

---

### Python

A native Python way is to use the [`s.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) as you described, and then 'splice' the array and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.join) them back together in groups of 2 using a `for` loop with [`range(0, len(s), 2)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to take steps of 2:

```py
s = 'john had a little blue car'
s = s.split(" ")
s = [' '.join(s[i : i + 2]) for i in range(0, len(s), 2)]
```

##### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYoxDsMgEAR7XrFyAyiWZTldpLzEckESHM4iBzpIkdcT5G52dvKvhsTX1uiTk1SIV6rgDn2kwAjuBYdItUaPR/x6PJ3oMyhTyf0wAwZ7ilVDT0ciNmUl3EC4YNks9iSdiSGO397MI6LvjR2x2E2pLMS1z9b@)

---

Both result in:

```json
['john had', 'a little', 'blue car']
```

Answer (score 1):

**Not the fastest way** to be honest:

```
s = 'john had a little blue car'.split()

for i in range(0, len(s), 2):
    print(f"{s[i]} {s[i+1]}")
```

Where: `s[i]` - first elem of pair, `s[i+1]` - second elem of a pair

Comment: This is the same as my answer? Just not a one-liner??

Comment: @0stone0 We answered at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'john had a little blue car'.split(' ')    
#['john', 'had', 'a', 'little', 'blue', 'car']

s[0::2]
#['john', 'a', 'blue']

s[1::2]
#['had', 'little', 'car']


list(zip(s[0::2],s[1::2]))
#[('john', 'had'), ('a', 'little'), ('blue', 'car')]
```

Or for desired output:

```
[' '.join(x) for x in zip(s[0::2],s[1::2])]
#['john had', 'a little', 'blue car']
```

Answer (score 0):

The result you wants is a bit blurry, but here a few ways

1. Using for loop to iterate over the string and combining pairs of words together:

   ```
    s = 'john had a little blue car'
    words = s.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words), 2):
        w1 = words[i]
        w2 = words[i+1]
        print(w1, w2)
   ```

if you want to save the result than :

```
    s = 'john had a little blue car'
    split_list = []
    words = s.split()
    for i in range(0, len(words), 2):
            w1 = words[i]
            w2 = words[i+1]
            split_list.append([w1, w2])
```

after the code you will have in split_list in each cell the 2 of the words

2. Using the zip function to iterate over the string and combining pairs of words
   together (Might not familiar with Zip but its a very helpful tool):

   ```
    s = 'john had a little blue car'
    words = s.split()
    for w1, w2 in zip(words[::2], words[1::2]):
        print(w1, w2)
   ```

if you want to save the result than :

```
    s = 'john had a little blue car'
    split_list = []
    words = s.split()
    for w1, w2 in zip(words[::2], words[1::2]):
        split_list.append([w1, w2])
```

after the code you will have in split_list in each cell the 2 of the words

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that will get the results you want.

```
s = 'john had a little blue car'
print '\n'.join(' '.join([s.split()[i].strip(), s.split()[i+1] if i < len(s.split()) - 1 else '']) for i in range(0, len(s.split()), 2))
```

Output:

```
john had
a little
blue car
```

Edit: Modified slightly to prevent errors when there are an odd number of words.